# After .htaccess login but does not direct properly

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a `.htaccess` to protect the `conf` directory. The `.htaccess` code was generated by the 000webhost at the `cPanel`.

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW PWPROTECTID:******
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /home/a*******/public_html/test/conf/.htpasswd
Require user demo
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE ******:PWPROTECTID
```

And here is my `.htpasswd`. The password I changed after hosting created the `.htpasswd`.

```
demo:demo
```

I am able to login with the username and password. But after login, I am redirected to the [error page](http://error404.000webhost.com/), where I should be in `Index.php`.

I'm using free hosting at 000webhost. And here is the [link](http://anonynewbie.site11.com/conf/Index.php) to the login.

Is it the limitation by free hosting, or error in the `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your password must be crypt with the php [crypt](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.crypt.php) function. So replace `demo:demo` by `demo:h/TJ69Uv5nPfE` in your htpassword file.

And, after, if the problem persists, check if the redirection file exists. Otherwise, contact your host.

Comment: I have tried the password that encrypted by the hosting. But I still get the improper redirection. If password wrong, I won't get into the error page too.

Comment: Can you access to your files with FTP ? Because maybe there are no files in your conf directory

Comment: Yes, there is `.htpasswd` in the `conf` directory. If the `.htpasswd` unable to be found by the `.htaccess`, server will just keep asking for username and password, isn't?

Comment: If the file exists and if the combinaison pseudo/password is good, no problem should be expected. So, I think you have to solve this problem with your host.